# AngulaJS routing is not working and it is not throwing me any errors

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to implement routing in the AngulaJS sample app but somehow it is not working and it is also not throwing any kind of errors. Please help me out here. I'm totally stuck here from last one day.

Here are the code details:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AngularJS">
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../Styles/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/Vendors/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Vendors/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Controllers/Index.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="header">
                <h2>Website header</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftMenu">
                <a href="#/Home">Home</a>
                <a href="#/Courses">Courses</a>
            </td>
            <td class="mainContent">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                <b>Website footer</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('AngularJS', ['ngRoute']);
```

Index.js

```
angular.module('AngularJS')
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Home', {
                templateUrl: 'Templates/Home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            })
            .when('/Courses', {
                templateUrl: 'Templates/Courses.html',
                controller: 'CoursesController'
            });
     })
     .controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'Home page';
     })
     .controller('CoursesController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Courses = [
            'C', 'C++', 'C#', 'SQL Server', 'AngularJS', 'ASP.NET MVC'
        ];
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that angular or angularjs? This question couldn't be more confusing

Comment: It's AngularJS... sorry about it

Comment: can you show your error message

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: There aren't any errors.

Comment: I think you should add ,angular.module('AngularJS',[ "ngRoute"]) in your index.js

Comment: I already tried that out but still not working. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. Check if you have added the correct angular.js and angular-route.js references.

Also check for your path of the templates.

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Here is the working **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4e8pF1Mc8eGo6j8yMr26?p=preview)**

Comment: if he missed that one it will always show an error sir.

Comment: yes right! hope he has not added any expression on the templates to display the information

Comment: Bingo.. I added the CDN links for AngularJS and route.js and it did work. I don't know what's wrong with my static reference. Static ref is working for the entire application except this one.

Comment: Anyway lots of Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `href` use this code

```
<td class="leftMenu">
    <a href="/#/Home">Home</a>
    <a href="/#/Courses">Courses</a>
</td>
```

You just missed one forward slash.

Comment: If I add one forward slash then it is showing me the IIS error page afte clicking the link

Comment: it's not an answer

Comment: By "If" does it mean you didnt try it yet? I'm using that to all my sites and not a single problem to me